# Meteor.js : meteor is using angular 1.3 version instead of 1.5

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using meteor 1.3, App is forcibly using angular 1.3 though i have installed 1.5.7 version. Kindly help me figure out the problem here.

I have installed list of dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.5.7",
"angular-meteor": "^1.3.11",
"angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
"interact.js": "^1.2.6",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"massive": "^2.3.0",
"meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
"moment": "^2.13.0",
"q": "^1.4.1"
}
```

and meteor packages as follows:

```
accounts-google                     1.0.10  Login service for Google    accounts
autopublish                         1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Publish     the entire database to all cli...
check                               1.2.2* Check whether a value matches a pattern
email                               1.0.13* Send email messages
es5-shim                            4.5.11* Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
http                                1.1.6* Make HTTP calls to remote servers
insecure                            1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
jquery                              1.11.9  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
meteor-base                         1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mizzao:bootboxjs                    4.4.0  Programmatic dialog boxes using Twitter's bootstrap modals
mobile-experience                   1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                               1.1.8* Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
pbastowski:angular-babel            1.3.6  Babel compiler and ng-annotate for Meteor 1.3
planettraining:angular-ui-calendar  0.0.6  Fullcalendar as ui-component
promise                             0.7.2* ECMAScript 2015 Promise polyfill with Fiber support
reactive-var                        1.0.10  Reactive variable
standard-minifier-css               1.0.7* Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js                1.0.7* Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                             1.0.14  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap                      3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsiv...
urigo:static-templates              0.0.5* Meteor plugin for importing static HTML templates
```

Comment: Have you tried `meteor add angularjs:angular@=1.5.7`?

Comment: i got this error: no such version angularjs:angular@1.5.7

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1159) you should try `meteor add angular:angular@1.5.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor package planettraining:angular-ui-calendar was pulling Angular 1.3 (dependency) due to that it was replacing angular 1.5.7 package installed through NPM.

Comment: so did you get angular-ui-calendar from npm instead?

Comment: I dint use meteor package because of its dependency (angular 1.3.15). NPM package may work (i haven't tried) because it has no angular dependency in its package